# Can't Connect to Local Mysql from terminal

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

NOTE: The full discussion to the answer in this question is in a chat link in the comment section below, above the submitted answers.

The summarized answer is in checked answer.

After meddling with installing the gem for mysql2 and successfully doing that I type

```
which mysql
```

and it returns

```
mysql: aliased to nocorrect mysql
```

I'm not sure what this means.

Then I type in

```
 mysql --version
```

and it outputs

```
 mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.20, for osx10.7 (i386) using readline 5.1
```

So I know mysql is installed.

Finally I want to configure a database for my rails app so, from within the correct directory I type:

```
 mysql -u root -p
```

It asks me for a password and, since there is none, I leave it blank. It outputs this:

```
 ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)
```

I've been reading around for a solution but I don't understand any of them. Like finding a file called my.cnf or a folder called etc within the rails framework files...

Comment: please show the output from `alias`

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that. the "mysql: aliased to no correct mysql" is all it outputted.

Comment: type `alias` and press return at the command line.  Literally that :)

Comment: and if unix, which shell (zsh or bash).

Comment: omg that returned a MASSIVE list of things. I'm on Mac lion osx

Comment: btw you have "nocorrect" at top but "no correct" above.

Comment: ok, look thru that list, do you see mysql, actually do the command again like this:  `alias | grep mysql` e.g. "pipe" the output to grep (a pattern matching search utility) and use mysql as the string to  search for.

Comment: Check this out... simple_cms ❯ mysql alias
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)

Comment: do you have this file:  `ls ~/.bash_aliases`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11899/discussion-between-michael-durrant-and-ninja08)

Comment: simple_cms ❯ alias | grep mysql                                                        ⏎
mysql='nocorrect mysql'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what finally allowed me to create a freaking database in my rails apps through terminal after dealing this error.

I downloaded mysql's .dmg 64 bit version from here:

http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/

and then I followed the instructions in the README file. That was the most important part.

Thanks for the help everyone.

EDIT:

This didn't answer the question entirely for me since mysql stopped working.

After installing .dmg version I had to update the bash_profile file.

Here is where the instructions are:

[Should I reinstall Mysql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10844762/should-i-reinstall-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

It's trying to connect over unix sockets instead of tcp/ip.  Try adding -h  param eg

```
mysql -h localhost -u root -p
```

**edit:** Just read your question a bit closer.  "mysql" being installed just means you have a client, not the server itself.  Check you have **mysqld** installed.

Comment: when I type "which mysqld" it gives me a path to mysqld

Comment: I think you're not actually running the mysqld server process.  On linux you would normally use an init.d startup script, but I don't know what to do on mac.

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql --socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock -u root -p
```

[also read this](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/762/solve-cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-tmpmysqlsock/)

Comment: In that page you provided I pasted this command in, and it seemed to have worked because now I have a new error, although it's an error that someone else told me they are having. I'm assuming this is just another error in a series of errors to get past. 

alias mysql=”mysql –socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock”