# Should I reinstall Mysql?

Tags: mysql, osx-lion

I'm getting kind of desperate here trying to get mysql to work on osx lion.

I've been through nearly every article on the web these past few days looking for a way to fix the problem with the error.

When I try to start the server is gives this error:

Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)

when I try to create a database with 'rake db:create' it gives the same error.

sometimes it says that or I get errors about "please install gem-blabhalbhabhlb". And that gem doesn't exist.

I was able to install mysql in terminal using the dmg version from mysql's site but after I deleted the installation files it just stopped working- as in when I run

rake cd:create

I get the mysql.sock error.

I'm going insane.. please help

Comment: Can you connect to mysql via command line?

Comment: nope it gives the mysql.sock error. I don't know if deleting the installation packs make a difference or not since before I deleted them I was able to run the server by typing mysql in terminal

Comment: Does the file /tmp/mysql.sock exist? If not stop mysql and do a touch /tmp/mysql.sock. Try starting /usr/local/bin/safe_mysqld afterwards.

Comment: when I did touch it didn't output anything. It just went to the next line, ready to take more input. When I search for safe_mysqld it says it says no such file or directory

Comment: Can you do this? sudo /Library/StartupItems/MySQLCOM/MySQLCOM start

Comment: Do you have this dir /usr/local/mysql? There is suppose to be a bin dir containing mysqld_safe or safe_mysqld

Comment: it said it can't find any matching directory for that

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12013/discussion-between-john-p-and-ninja08)

Comment: Off-topic for SO; belongs on serverfault

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Major credit to John P. for helping me get this working last night

The first thing was to uninstall mysql using 'brew uninstall mysql'.

Then to install mysql from their development site. The community .dmg 64 bits version.

Then to find out where the path was pointing.

So in updating the paths he had to find where bin/mysql was and make sure bash_profile had it's path there.

```
PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/mysql/bin
```

The essential step after that was to 'source' the file so he had me run this command.

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

From there mysql works flawlessly.

Answer (score 0):

For me I often need to force mysql to not use unix sockets, but regular php sockets.
To do this, connect to 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost. Works 90% of the time, all the time.